# Parse Update Object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have the following code:

```
//start the update
    var query2 = PFQuery(className:"\(selectedShow)_schedule")
    query2.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(idOfObject) {
        (objectSend: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            objectSend["student"] = "test"
            objectSend.saveEventually()
            println("ran")
        }
    }
```

And when I try to run it, it gives me the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and highlights this line:

```
objectSend["student"] = "test"
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you check if(objectSend ==nil) return; condition?

Comment: Sorry for my late response... I checked it and the variable does in fact return nil. Is this a problem with the way I set up my callback block?

Comment: YEs it might be possible. There is something wrong with your callback.

Comment: Ok, how can we fix it?

Comment: I fixed it! The variable was not set as an optional, which is required.

Answer (score 0):

The variable was not wrapped with an optional.